# Is there official documentation for `alias` in Ruby 2.x?

Tags: ruby-2.0, ruby-2.1

I can't seem to find any documentation for Ruby's `alias` keyword in Ruby 2.

I can find lots of non-official pages that talk about it, but nothing official.

Is there an RDoc or something for `alias`?

**Note:** I'm not talking about `alias_method`, which *does* have documentation.  I'm talking about the plain old `alias` keyword.

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/miscellaneous_rdoc.html#label-alias

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-alias

Comment: @Зелёный - if you make that an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: @ArupRakshit - thanks.  I was actually looking for Ruby 2.0, though.  I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: This is a **keyword**, nothing has been changed in the newer version of Ruby. So you can trust on the link I have given. :-)

Comment: Without seeing 2.x docs, how could I be sure that it hasn't changed since 1.9?  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in `Miscellaneous Syntax` on [`Ruby-Doc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/miscellaneous_rdoc.html#label-alias)

Comment: Definitely not an obvious place to look.  Thanks.